What is wrong in the following derivation of Gravitational Potential Energy?
By definition, the gravitational potential energy of a test mass $m$ at some distance $r$ from mass $M =$ Work done by an external agent (force $\vec F_{ext}$) in bringing mass $m$ from $\infty$ to the point $r$ without any increase in kinetic energy.
Now, for no considerable velocity $$a = 0 \implies F_{net}= 0 \implies F_{ext} = F_{g}$$ (magnitude only)
Also, we choose the increasing distance as the positive direction of $x$-axis and the center of mass $M$ as the zero.
Now, let $W$ be the work done by external force $F_{ext}$
Then, $$dW= \vec F_{ext}\cdot  \vec{dr} = F_{ext}\ dr\ \cos(\pi) = \large{-F_{ext}\ dr},$$ as $\vec{dr}$ points towards the negative direction and while $F_{ext}$ points towards the positive direction.
Integrating both sides we get,
$$W = {\Large\int}_\infty^r\left(-\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}\right)dr = \dfrac{GMm}r,$$ which is incorrect.
Why is the the expression for potential energy incorrect when the vector laws have been applied correctly and integration is also right? Which step, assumption, or process is erroneous.

I think it just an issue with sign conventions. If you start with $\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$ you will end up with $\dfrac{-GMm}{r}$ after the integration which is the usual expression for gravitational potential.

It isn't. If it is could you accurately point out which step is erroneous.

You said "Also, we choose the increasing distance as the positive direction of x
-axis and the center of mass M as the zero." That is just a choice.

Although I mentioned it again, it was already assumed in the definition: Work done by an external agent (force external) in bringing mass m from ∞ to the point r without any increase in kinetic energy. This is what almost all school and college courses use for Newtonian Mechanics.

You have an unnecessary extra minus sign in your expression for $dr$. The work is always just $F\cdot dr$ and the sign of $dr$ is determined by your limits of integration. When you integrate from $\infty$ to $R$ you are automatically making $dr$ negative so you do not need to add an extra minus sign.

@JohnRennie You saved me. I was struggling with this for two days. Thanks.

@JohnRennie When a spring is being compressed, it exerts a force in the positive direction (let) of $x$-axis $kx$. Let 0 is the mean position of the spring and the displacement in the negative direction is $-x$.
$W_{spring} =\int_0^{-x} kx dx$ = $\frac 1 2 kx^2$. But actually it should be negative.
I think that it is $x^2$ that has caused this problem.
